# How do I instantiate an object in java?

Tags: java

this is what i have so far

```
// Read in two names and print out information about each using
// methods in the Name class.
//------------------------------------------------------------------
public static void main(String[] args)
{
String first, middle, last;
    // DECLARE AN OBJECT NAMED name1
    // DECLARE AN OBJECT NAMED name2
    Name name1 = new Name();

    Name name2 = new Name();
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("\nName Program\n");
System.out.println ("Name of first person...");
System.out.print ("Enter the first name: ");
first = scan.nextLine();
System.out.print ("Enter the middle name: ");
middle = scan.nextLine();
System.out.print ("Enter the last name: ");
last = scan.nextLine();

// INSTANTIATE THE name1 OBJECT AND PASS ITS CONSTRUCTOR THE 
// first, middle, AND last VARIABLES
public name1
    this.Object = name1
```

Comment: we're not your homework service, please refer to your course material or other tutorials, the internet is thick with them.

Answer (score 1):

If you have java class Name:

```
public class Name {
    private String first;
    private String middle;
    private String last;

    public Name(String first, String middle, String last) {
        this.first = first;
        this.middle = middle;
        this.last = last;
    }

    public String getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public String getMiddle() {
        return middle;
    }

    public String getLast() {
        return last;
    }
}
```

Then you should instantiate an instance like this:

```
String first = "First name";
String middle = "Middle name";
String last = "Last name";
Name name = new Name(first, middle, last);
```

Now you can get it's properties via getters (`getFirst()` etc).